# ByteArrayInputStream to ObjectInputStream disappeared

Tags: java, io, objectinputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I've something that I don't understand, please help.

```
System.out.println("\n" + Arrays.toString(buffer) + "\n");
System.out.println("buffer.length = " + buffer.length + "\nnew ByteArrayInputStream(buffer).available() is: " + new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer).available());
ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer));
System.out.println("input.available(): " + input.available());
```

Its output is below:

```
[-84, -19, 0, 5]

buffer.length = 4
new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer).available() is: 4
input.available(): 0
```

I'm so confused why a byte array of 4 valid bytes, after putting into ObjectInputStream, it becomes zero.

Things I've tried:

1. Initially, I was doubting my byte array was empty, but as you see, I printed out, its length is 4.
2. Then I thought my byte might be invalid, so I printed out each byte, as you can see, those four bytes are all valid.

So, I'm lost why this is happening.

Please help, thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the input data? At 4 bytes, it seems unlikely to be an object.  As the docs say, `An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.`

Comment: How can I show the input? I thought Arrays.toString(buffer) was the best I could show.

Comment: So here's the issue in my previous comment:  `data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream`. You don't do this. You are reading raw bytes that have never passed through an `ObjectInputStream`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As the other answer mentioned, `available` only means the number of bytes you can read before blocking occurs.

It is my guess, however, that you didn't follow the rules of the `ObjectInputStream`, which specify `An ObjectInputStream deserializes primitive data and objects previously written using an ObjectOutputStream.`

In other words, in order to actually read the data with an `ObjectInputStream`, you first must have written the data using an `ObjectOutputStream` of some kind. Here's an example showing this with the data you provided:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[]{-84,-19,0,5};
ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream objectOutputStream= new ObjectOutputStream(out);
objectOutputStream.write(buffer);
objectOutputStream.flush();

ObjectInput input = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray()));
System.out.println("input.available(): " + input.available());
System.out.println("input.readByte(): " + input.readByte());
```

(I'll add that I very rarely work with IO in Java, so the above may not be best practice or have superfluous code.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, it definitely deepens my understanding! ^ ^

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html#available()) is the javadoc of `available` method and this is what it says:

> Returns the number of bytes that can be read without blocking.

So, it does not return the total number of `bytes` present in your array/read, it returns the number of `bytes` it can read before getting blocked. So, it returning 0 is a valid scenario.

Now, let's have a look at javadoc of [**ObjectInputStream**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html), here is the brief explanation:

> Non-object reads which exceed the end of the allotted data will
>   reflect the end of data in the same way that they would indicate the
>   end of the stream: bytewise reads will return -1 as the byte read or
>   number of bytes read, and primitive reads will throw EOFExceptions. If
>   there is no corresponding writeObject method, then the end of default
>   serialized data marks the end of the allotted data.

What you are trying to do in your code is to `read` the primitive data (or reading without `WriteObject` method), as it is not valid data (for `ObjectInputStream`) `read` will always return -1. And I was able to reproduce `EOFException`just by calling `readObject` method.

I then tried writing/reading a new object and tested `available` method call, have a look at the below snippet:

```
byte[] buffer = new byte[]{-84, -19, 0, 5};
System.out.println("\n" + Arrays.toString(buffer) + "\n");
ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer);
System.out.println("buffer.length = " + buffer.length + "\nnew ByteArrayInputStream(buffer).available() is: " + new ByteArrayInputStream(buffer).available());
ObjectInputStream input = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
System.out.println("input.available(): " + input.available());
//      System.out.println(input.readObject()); //Uncomment to see EOFException

Date date = new Date();
System.out.println(date);
ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOut = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
ObjectOutputStream out = new ObjectOutputStream(byteArrayOut);
out.writeObject(date);
byte[] bytes = byteArrayOut.toByteArray();

input = new ObjectInputStream(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
System.out.println(input.available());
System.out.println(input.readObject());
```

The code `reads` the already written object and prints the value. Please note that even though it reads the object correctly and prints the same object, `available` method still returns 0. So, I would recomment not to rely too much on `available` because of it's misleading name :)